# is it possible to draw line with graphael with combination of positive and negative numbers?

Tags: graphael

I have some numbers including positive and negative and I want to show them in a format of line(lind chart or trending ) . I found gRaphael very interesting and I saw a couple of examples shows that it works with positive numbers perfectly but I am wondering if it works with combination of positive and negative numbers? (since I want the format like below).Has anyone had exprience like that with gRaphael?

[image]